# PHPMailer comma seperated emails

Tags: mysql, phpmailer

I have a database field that contains emails seperated by a comma as below

email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com, etc etc

I am using PHP Mailer and have found several articles on here explaining how to loop through each email to add each email to the emailto address

I'm clearly doing something wrong as my code below only sends to one email

```
$sql="SELECT Email FROM Managers WHERE Company = '$name';"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));  

        $address = explode (',' , $row['Email']);

        foreach ($address as $key => $v) {$mail->addAddress($key);}
```

When I output the result to check the output I just see all the emails as one string with no commas

Any advice would be most appreciated as from what I have read on here this should work.

UPDATE: I now have this working as below. Thanks for your help:

```
$sql="SELECT Email FROM Managers WHERE Company = '$name';"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

    $address = $row['Email'];
    $address2 =  explode (',',$address);

    foreach ($address2 as $v) {$mail->addAddress($v);}
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you output? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Hi Nico, ive added in var dump so i can see what the query is picking up. Ive also just looked at the result of the initial database query to check that is working ok. When i look at the exploded output it just shows the comma seperated values from the DB but without the comma. Ive tried changing the delimiter and triple checked the data for spaces etc. I also added 'trim' into the code just in case. I've made the change pointed out by Synchro. I've come to a bit of dead end !!! My thoughts are im doing something really stupid wrong, but if I am I just cant see it !!

Comment: Please share the code for dumping, and the result of dumping this data

Comment: Hi.

I am using:

var_dump (explode(',', $row['Email']));
var_dump (explode(',', $v));

Output is: array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

Im also outputting the PHPMailer error:
Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.

Which is pretty clear !!!

But it should be finding an email address as the sql look up is definitley finding a match

Thanks

Comment: Please add all such explanation to your question by editing it. If the exploded array is empty, the problem lies somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Always check what your code is *really* doing, don't assume it's doing what you think it is.

There is a simple bug in your code:

```
foreach ($address as $key => $v) {$mail->addAddress($key);}
```

Should be:

```
foreach ($address as $v) {$mail->addAddress($v);}
```

otherwise you're submitting the column name as the email address.

Comment: Thanks very much Synchro. Ive made that change but unfortunately it is not working. The output I get when checking is:

array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } dean@xxx.co.ukdean@yyy.com

The raw data from the database is as below:
'dean@xxx.co.uk,dean@yyy.com'

Thanks

Comment: That *doesn't* look like the output from `var_dump($row)` as it should have an associative index. Please add more of what you've tried and your output to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I have now added var_dump($row) which is bringing back NULL

var_dump(explode(',',($v)) returns:
array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "dean@yyy.com" } - that is one of the emails in the comma seperated string

Ive checked there are no spaces in the data and have tried changing the delimeter just in case.

I added more email addresses to the string and each time the code just pulls out the last one in the row.

Currently the code is not emailing anyone (just to be clear I am obviously changing the email domains.)

Thanks